# How to add prefix (label) and postfix to commerce price field

Tags: 7, theming, commerce

I am trying to implement Drupal Commerce in an existing site with existing nodes. In this process I need to replace the existing price field with the commerce price field. Since this field is locked, I cannot change the label.

So I thought I could use the raw price format and just add a prefix as a label in template.php or possibly in a hook in *.tpl.php file. But after spending hours googling without finding how to do this, I give up and post this question here. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% that I understand your question correctly but I assume you need to add prefix & suffix to your commerce product prices. In that case, [Drupal Commerce Extra Price Formatters](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_extra_price_formatters) does exactly that, have you tried using this module?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I managed to do this an other way, but I will look into this module as well.

Comment: @TBJ would you like to give more information around how you managed to do it so others can benefit too? Also, if you find one of the answers provided to be correct as well, can you mark them as such, thanks.

Comment: Hello I gave you an upvote. What I did was to programmatically in a custom module add code to fetch the price from Drupal commerce and set that price in an existing price field in the product node (raw format). That old price field was already styled as needed. So now everything looks as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using [Display suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds), you always can use a prefix/suffix using the expert options available in Display.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I will look into this. For now I managed to resolve the problem in another way.